# Are questions about standard syllabus on a course on-topic for the site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, scope

I want to ask a question about a standard syllabus for a **research methods and technical writing** course; but I am not sure whether it is on-topic for this site or not.

I seek advices on how the course should be arranged and what topics should be covered in it.

Comment: I agree in principle with @ff524, but must say that a course on "research methods and technical writing" is probably much more likely to be appropriate, given the audience than a course on math or biology. Basically your audience are effectively experts in "research methods and technical writing." It very much depends on the specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say definitively without seeing the specific question.

My intuition would be that just as a question about your work as a student in a particular class would be off topic (e.g. a question on mathematics for a mathematics class), so would a question about organizing/developing a particular class. The reason being that it's more a question about X (where X is the subject of the class) than a general question about teaching.

Comment: Thanks. I won't ask it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect site, potentially, to ask a question on what might go into a course on "research methods and technical writing." This is effectively what nearly every STEM academic spends a lot of time doing. I disagree that this is like asking a question about what math topic should be covered in a math class. The class could almost be titled "How to be an academic" perhaps you can phrase the question less about what belongs in your class specifically (as ff524 does have a good point, you don't want it to be too specific) and more about academic writing in general. I think this potentially works as question.

However, ff524 is right in general about the question in your title. I think it is the specific type of course you are talking about that offers an exception here.